# How can I save a hash in my rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on a rails application.

I need to save a key pair value like [user_email & user_phone] in a single attribute, I am thinking to use a hash with key user_email & value user_phone.

I have PostgreSQL DB with rails 6.0.3, How can I proceed with creating a hash in my DB ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with below steps :-

Add your **migration** with json type field. PostgreSQL has `json` and `jsonb` columns which can natively store your hash/object data and allow you to [query against the JSON with ActiveRecord!](https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2018/rails-postgres-query-json/)

```
class MigrationName
  def change
    add_column :table, :column_name, :json, default: {}
  end
end
```

Now in json column you can store hash like structure .

Comment: You're better off using `:jsonb`: ["The `json` data type stores an exact copy of the input text, which processing functions must reparse on each execution; while `jsonb` data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed. `jsonb` also supports indexing, which can be a significant advantage."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)